# What does the % sign mean in coding?

Tags: python

Like `%i` or `%yellow`? 
I'm not looking for it as an operator like `67%3`. But like this:

```
print("pink is %i" %grade)
```

what does the above code mean?

Comment: it is used to format code - to put value from `grade` in place of `%i` - you should first run code to see it - and ask later. BTW: [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: It's the wrong way to format a string. This is a very old style of string interpolation and should be left in the past in favor of more current approaches like `str.format` (`"pink is {:d}".format(grade)`) or its shortcut mechanism, the f-string (`f"pink is {grade:d}"`)

Answer (score 1):

It is used to format strings (you can read about string formatting in the [string docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), also mentioned in Input and Output - [old string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting)).

```
print("pink is %i" %10)
```

Output

> pink is 10